# How to write to a HTML file a string containing < and > with command echo?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I am using batch file to write to a file, and want to not add the same thing if it already being added. I have tried this which has worked.

```
find "jackdows loves me" %appdata%\data.html || echo jackdows loves me >>%appdata%\data.html
```

However, I can't make this one work as there are special chars:

```
find "<!-- saved from url=(0017)http://localhost/ -->" %appdata%\data.html || echo <!--  saved from url=(0017)http://localhost/ --> >>%appdata%\data.html
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: I notice that the strings for  `find` and `echo` are not equal (one vs. two spaces before the word "saved") Might it be, that you search for the wrong string (or is it just a typing error)? Besides that, @DavidHoelzer's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To escape < and > in anything in the NT line of OSs, use the caret:

echo ^< > test.out

Comment: Correct. :)  That's all there is to it.

Comment: it works, but it always adds the data, doesnt look if its already added or not. Here is a line I used for find "^<!-- saved from url=(0017)http://localhost/ --^>" %appdata%\data.html || echo ^<!-- saved from url=(0017)http://localhost/ --^>>>%appdata%\data.html

Comment: I've never tried it but I was surprised that || worked in that way in a Batch script at all, but I assumed you were correct because you claimed it functioned in another context...  I don't know what to tell you about that.. I would have approached this with an if ERRORLEVEL check, but the caret solved the question that you asked. :)

Comment: Its very strange. Do you suggest me file check ? I have used this but it also gives me "... is not expected" error. IF EXIST %APPDATA/data.html ( )

Comment: Well, certainly.. but I meant that I would have run the find and then done an IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO...  You may want to double check, but my memory says that if FIND doesn't find what you search for it sets ERRORLEVEL to 1.  Makes the logic two lines but, as I said, I don't remember being able to do an DO A || DO B in a Batch script. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: `||` works as "if previous command failed, then". `&&` works as "if previous command was successful, then".

Comment: Yes, that's pretty cool.  I use that structure in lots of other languages; it never occurred to me that it might function in Batch.